# Srt text to latex

Tags: conversion

I have extracted subtitle text in [`.srt` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip).

It is essentially text with some keywords that indicate which type of formating to apply to different parts.

Formatting is derived from HTML tags for bold, italic, underline and color:

Bold – `<b> ... </b>` or `{b} ... {/b}`

Italic – `<i> ... </i>` or `{i} ... {/i}`

Underline – `<u> ... </u>` or `{u} ... {/u}`

Font color – `<font color="color name or #code"> ... </font>` (as in HTML)

Now, I would like to convert it to LaTeX format. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is a sample data:

```
37
00:03:28,544 --> 00:03:32,544
Maintenant une équation linéaire à deux inconnues

38
00:03:32,544 --> 00:03:36,544
est de la forme : 
<i>c·aᵢ₁(α₁ - β₁) + c·aᵢ₂(α₂ - β₂) + ... + c·aₙ₁(αₙ - βₙ)) = 0.</i>,

39
00:03:37,841 --> 00:03:44,091
je nomme cette fois les inconnues <i>x</i> et <i>y</i>, où <i>a</i>, <i>b</i> et <i>c</i> sont des nombres réels.
```

I extract the text using [pysub2](https://github.com/tkarabela/pysubs2)

```
Maintenant une équation linéaire à deux inconnues est de la forme :

<i>c·aᵢ₁(α₁ - β₁) + c·aᵢ₂(α₂ - β₂) + ... + c·aₙ₁(αₙ - βₙ)) = 0.</i>, 

je nomme cette fois les inconnues <i>x</i> et <i>y</i>, où <i>a</i>, 
<i>b</i> et <i>c</i> sont des nombres réels.
```

I would like to have exactly the same text in Latex form, but of course, without the formatting tags (i.e.  etc.) but with Latex formatting (for instance: `\textit{c}` instead of `<i>c</i>`

Comment: What is srt format?

Comment: @Johannes_B please see my edited question.

Comment: Why do you want to convert this to a pdf? Isn't it completely useless in this format?

Comment: @Johannes_B It depends for what you need it. In my case, it is not useless.

Comment: Isn't srt just text? You can just copy/paste it. LaTeX is also just text.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, but I want to preserve formating.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45550/i-just-want-to-have-the-text-in-my-pdf-the-same-way-i-have-it-in-my-editor

Comment: @james If `verbatim` or `listings` are not ok for you, then explain your question further and show what you want.

Comment: @JouleV Please have a look at my updated question. The srt file is essentially text with keywords indicating which formating to apply.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the link. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: @james (+1) Now I can see that your question is interesting! This is related (not a duplicate, of course): [Converting Markdown to LaTeX, in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101717/converting-markdown-to-latex-in-latex).

Comment: Have you looked on the pandoc side? https://pandoc.org

Comment: @AndréC sounds intresting, but I cannot find srt conversion

Comment: Since they are HTML tags, convert from HTML to LaTeX

Comment: @AndréC good point. It seems a good path to take. If it is not too much asked, Maybe you could create an answer with a sample srt file in which you guide us step by step of how to convert it using your envisioned method.

Comment: I have never created a.srt code, you should indicate in your question how you created it and give the result.

Comment: @AndréC I added a sample srt.code. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: @james The first problem we face here is character encoding. Indeed, `β₂` is not the way LaTeX writes this character. LaTeX writes this `$\beta_2$`. So, you need to find a way to convert the characters encoded in this way to LaTeX code. There are specialists in coding and fonts, perhaps they can explain how to proceed. Ask a new question.

Comment: Listings etc. could easily handle some parts of the conversion but would need some care in its ordering that would take multiple samples to get right thus a simple answer to your mwe would not work instantly with the next but over a few cycles could. so starting with `{<i>}` replace with `{\textit{}{8}` and replace `{</i>}` with `{}}`{1} replacing `{β₂}` with {$\beta_2$}{9) is easy but the large number of variations would be time consuming It may be as said easier to use a dedicated string replacement program to do the conversion then simply \include that output

Comment: Looks like a LuaLaTeX task to me.....